# Conflict on Template of Twig and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, vue.js

I'm doing a program using Slim 2 that uses Twig as my templating engine. so It uses the syntax `{{ foo }}` in php file. On the other hand, I'm using vue.js, it also uses `{{ bar }}`.

E.g.

I'm gonna do the two way binding, below is my html code.

```
<div class="container">
    Label Value: <label>{{ foo }}</label><br>
    Field Value: <input v-model="foo">
</div>
```

and here is my vue js code.

```
new Vue({

    el: '.container',
    data: {
        foo: 'Hello world.'
    }
});
```

So the Hello world should be in the Label Value.

The output is the image below.

[image]

Which it did not worked, probably the system thought it's a twig variable. So I checked by passing variable in a view.

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('login.php', [
        'foo' => 'FROM PHP FILE'
    ]);
})->name('login');
```

So I checked, the Label Value: shows the variable that I passed from the PHP file not on the VUE code.

Kind of hard to explain but you get the point. Was wondering how to bypass twig's template and use the `{{  }}` from vue also.

[image]

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just change default delimiters for vue. Here's how:

#### Vue.js 1.0

Define delimiters globally ([docs](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#delimiters)).

```js
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}']
```

---

#### Vue.js 2.0

Define delimiters for component ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters)).

```js
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

---

#### Vue.js 3.0

Define delimiters for application ([docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#delimiters)).

```js
Vue.createApp({
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

Answer (score 62):

In this case you can either change vue.js tag marker (if any) or use twig verbatim tag (much better in my opinion) which mark a section as raw text which shouldn't be evaluated by twig parser. i.e:

```
{% verbatim %}
    new Vue({

        el: '.container',
        data: {
            foo: 'Hello world.'
        }
    });
{% endverbatim %}
```

**From the twig docs:**

> The verbatim tag marks sections as being raw text that should not be
>   parsed. For example to put Twig syntax as example into a template you
>   can use this snippet:

- [Verbatim tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)

Comment: Ohh! I saw that also but did not bother trying it, instead I tried autoescape and which did not worked. Hahaha. Now I tried that and it worked, I put that verbatim syntax between my vue " {% verbatim %} {{ foo }} {% endverbatim %} and it works! Thanks! :)

Comment: For old twig version, you can use `raw` tag instead of `verbatim`

Answer (score 17):

I read in another similar question to do:

```
{{"{{vue.js variable here}}"}}
```

to make it shorter. It works in SOME cases for me. But, thought you might like to see it anyway...

I didn't yet succeed to get it to work in all areas of my code.

Comment: Hello there, I will try this one and will let you know if this works. :)

Comment: The previous answer from felipsmartins is better... it works in all cases. The above I sent seems to have limited uses... as far as my tests showed anyway.

Comment: Lifesaver for short variables and closest analog to laravel blade's `@{{ variable }}` escape.
Mind sharing where exactly your solution didn't work?

Answer (score 9):

For Vue JS 2 (not sure about 1). You can use:

```
<span v-text="msg"></span>
<!-- same as -->
<span>{{msg}}</span>
```

As per documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up. On Vue JS 2. The way of doing this is add an object to Vue.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing delimiters, making components less reusable or using less readable double escaping mechanisms, you can use Twig's [`source`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/source.html) function.

> The source function returns the content of a template without rendering it:
>
> ```
> {{ source('template.html') }}
> {{ source(some_var) }}
> ```

**Example:**

```
<!-- path/to/twig_template.html.twig -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
    {{ source('path/to/vue-template.html') }}
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('my-component', {
        template: '#my-template'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What was the down voting for? Please comment, when down voting!

Comment: Now that's nicer. no idea why the downvote but I just made up for that...

Answer (score 2):

Also, for those who don't want to change vue's delimiter, you can change Twig delimiter (using Silex php framework in this example):

```
$app->before(function() use ($app){
    $app['twig']->setLexer( new Twig_Lexer($app['twig'], [
        'tag_comment'   => ['[#', '#]'],
        'tag_block'     => ['[%', '%]'],
        'tag_variable'  => ['[[', ']]'],
        'interpolation' => ['#[', ']'],
    ]));
});
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not to change either ones delimiter.

You can use the vuejs markup in twig like so

```
{{ mytwigvar }} {{ '{{' }} myvuevar {{ '}}' }}
```

This obviously is suboptimal, so redefine your twig loader to preprocess files and replace `{{{` with `{{ '{{' }}` and `}}}` with `{{ '}}' }}` then you can write the markup as

```
{{ mytwigvar }} {{{ myvuevar }}}
```

Much nicer.

Comment: 'nicer' -> that's very subjective. I don't think that's nicer, obviously you do though...still, it's good you put it in..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VueJs v2, with the syntax below:

```
<img id="bookCover" style="border:none;width:200px" :src="book.cover">
```

Where book.cover is one of the myVueInstance.$data.book fields.

[Here's the docs](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working - vue js vars in twig template:

```
    new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       delimiter: ['{}'], // any delimiter you would like
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works the combination:
delimiters: ['${', '}']
and
${VueVariable}