# Can SimpleTemplate ignore variables in a template file?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, vue.js, bottle

We're trying to build a simple web application based on bottle and using the SimpleTemplate module to template files. The site is built using Vue.js.

The bottle templates syntax is {{ }}, which [Vue.js also uses for templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html). So we will get KeyError exceptions for any Vue.js templates when bottle tries to run its template engine over our templates.

I've read the bottle [SimpleTemplate documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html), and other people talking about using SimpleTemplate, but this hasn't answered my question.

HTML including Vue.js template variable:

```html
<footer>
<p>© Copyright {{ thisYear }}</p>
</footer>
```

JavaScript:

```js
    <!-- ROUTING -->
    <script>
    // Create and mount the root instance.
    const app = new Vue({
      router,
      data: {
        parentBaseUrl: '${service_url}/template',
        flash: '',
        open_menu: [],
        thisYear: new Date().getFullYear()
      }
```

The above are excepts of the HTML and JavaScript to avoid dumping the whole files.

**Is there some way I can configure SimpleTemplate (or another bottle template library) to ignore template variables?**

I've tried Googling if I can somehow escape the Vue.js template variables so SimpleTemplate doesn't replace them, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no obvious method to change the delimiters for SimpleTemplate / bottle, you should be able to change the template delimiters for Vue.js

Similar question for reference: [Conflict on Template of Twig and Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480612/conflict-on-template-of-twig-and-vue-js)

As explained in the answer for that question, you can change the template delimiters for Vue.js (version 2.0+) as follows:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

API docs reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: Thanks, changing the delimiters in Vue.js solved it for us.