# how to use a path twig in vueJS with Proyect Symfony - how to correctly use FSRouting

Tags: symfony, webpack, vuejs2, twig

I have a `Vue` code but I need to show a link in `twig`:

```
<template>
<div class="col t-blk text-center d-flex justify-content-around">                                                       
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md border-r-0 d-table py-2 px-4" href="{{path('corpasesoria')}}">Con Asesor</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md border-r-0 d-table py-2 px-4" id="step01-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#step01" role="tab" aria-controls="step01" aria-selected="false">Sin Asesor</a>
</div>
</template>
```

But when compiling webpack it shows an error in the link of twig and can not be advanced.

This is the error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                     00:58:12

 error  in ./assets/components/Corporativo/Corporativo.vue?vue&type=template&id=270a4b6a&scoped=true&

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 

  Errors compiling template:

  href="{{path('corpasesoria')}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.

  15 |                                                                                          <div class="row">
  16 |                                                                                                  <div class="col t-blk text-center d-flex justify-content-around">
  17 |                                                                                                          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md border-r-0 d-table py-2 px-4" href="{{path('corpasesoria')}}">Con Asesor</a>
     |                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  18 |                                                                                                          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md border-r-0 d-table py-2 px-4" id="step01-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#step01" role="tab" aria-controls="step01" aria-selected="false">Sin Asesor</a>
  19 |
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is the error: href="{{path('corpasesoria')}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conflict on Template of Twig and Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480612/conflict-on-template-of-twig-and-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [slmder-h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11535135/slmder-h)
First you need to install: npmjs.com/package/fos-routing

```
npm install fos-routing --save
```

Then you need to read the symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

After in the terminal

```
# Symfony Flex
bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js/fos_js_routes.json
```

Inside the file .vue or .js

```
const routes = require ('../../ public / js / fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData (routes);
Routing.generate ('asesoriajson');
```

Finally the Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/corporativo/asesoriajson",
 *     options = { "expose" = true },
 *     name = "asesoriajson",
 *       
 * )
 */
 public function asesoriajson(Request $request, SendMail $Sendmail)
 {
    $response = array();
    $response['type'] = null;
    $response['title'] = null;
    $response['message'] = null;

    $response['type'] = 'success';
    $response['title'] = 'Success';
    $response['message'] = 'Usted decidio utilizar un asesor'; 
    return new JsonResponse($response, 200);                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
import RoutingData from '../../../../dist/js/fos_js_routes';
```

import Routing from 'fos-routing';

Routing.setData(RoutingData);
export default Routing;

Comment: Now . I configure all but this is the error: "Error: "The route "corpasesoria" does not exist."" In vuejs this is the code: methods : { conAsesor: function (event) {
                        alert('Hello !') 
            Routing.generate('corpasesoria');
          }} 
What is the problem?

Comment: You need to dump your routes every time you add new route as described https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Comment: yes, this is the route in my controller: /**
  * @Route("/corporativo/asesoria",
  *     options = { "expose" = true },
  *     name = "corpasesoria",
  * )
  */ 
What is the problem??

Comment: Read documentation https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html. And dump your routes

Comment: Thanks. Now all work perfect. I'm going to correct the answer

Answer (score 0):

You ca try to use fosjsrouring bundle to generate links inside js 
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html

Comment: I use this form in twig:
Routing.generate('your_route_with_params', { param: varJavascript }); 
How use this routes in VueJS???

Comment: Usage is same in any js environment.