# How do I add min and max value to my Vue count value

Tags: vuejs2

The user can click on a `+` and `-` button to increment and decrement the value. How do I add a min and max value e.g. min = 1 and max = 10 for the `<span>[[ count ]]</span>`?

My `Vue.js` app:

```
<div id="app">
    <a class="btn" v-on:click="increment">Add 1</a>
    <a class="btn" v-on:click="decrement">Remove 1</a>

    <span>[[ count ]]</span>
  </div>

  <script>

    const App = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
      data() {
        return {
          min: 1,
          max: 10,
          count: 1
        }
      },
      methods: {
        increment() {
          this.count = this.count === this.max ? this.max : this.count + 1;
        },
        decrement() {
          this.count = this.count === this.min ? this.min : this.count + 1;
        }
      }
    })

  </script>
```

**Update:**
Above code is working now.

**1)** How do I change my `<span>[[ count ]]</span>` into an `<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />`, controlled by this buttons?

**2)** How do I add a class e.g `disabled` when [[ count ]] === 1?

**Update 2:**

I changed it to an input field:

```
  <input type="number" name="lineItems[{{ product.id }}][quantity]" value="{{ quantity }}" v-model.number="quantity" min="{{ product.minPurchase }}" max="{{ product.calculatedMaxPurchase }}" class="custom-qty__qty-field">
```

And make the input value adjustable by the min and plus buttons:

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
      data() {
        return {
          quantity: 1,
          max: {{ product.calculatedMaxPurchase }},
          min: {{ product.minPurchase }}
        }
      },
      methods: {
        increment() {
          //this.count++
          this.quantity = this.quantity === this.max ? this.max : this.quantity + 1;
        },
        decrement() {
          //this.count--
          this.quantity = this.quantity === this.min ? this.min : this.quantity - 1;
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
```

E.g `{{ product.minPurchase }}` are `twig` variables which contains settings from the ShopWare backend.

Is this a clean way? And how do I add a CSS class when the count reaches 1, so I can *disable* the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `count` is already at the limits during `increment` and `decrement` and act accordingly.

```js
increment() {
  this.count = this.count === 10 ? 10 : this.count + 1;
}
```

```js
decrement() {
  this.count = this.count === 1 ? 1 : this.count - 1;
}
```

You could also make `min` and `max` data properties instead of hardcoding `1` and `10` if you wanted.

## After your Edit:

If you use a number input instead, you could solve this without methods.  All that's needed is to bind your data to the input like this:

```html
<input type="number" v-model="count" :min="min" :max="max" />
```

See the demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      count: 1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="count" :min="min" :max="max" />
  
  <span class="instructions">&lt;&lt; Mouseover the input to change</span>
  <div class="count">Count: {{ count }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I updated my question. If I want to change my `<span>[[ count ]]</span>` to an `<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />` controlled by this buttons?

Comment: No problem.  I edited to reply to your new question

Comment: I needed the buttons (in combination with the input field). See my updated 2 question. Thanks

Comment: Now you know how to bind data properties to the template, use the buttons, and use the number input. You can combine this knowledge to do what you need. Never use `{{ }}` in the component JavaScript or inside of attributes: only between tags.  It's now a completely different question from your original, and it uses my answer from your 1st (and 2nd updated) question. It would be best now to ask a new question rather than to significantly change this one a 3rd time, introducing several new elements.

Comment: regarding the `{{ }}`. Those are Twig variables. In the backend there are settings assigned and in the Twig template they are rendered with e.g. `{{ product.minPurchase }}`. That's why I use in my Vue instance delimiters: `['[[',']]']`

Comment: Aha, that explains those.  Sometimes people try to use interpolation in the wrong spot.  I [read up on Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480612/conflict-on-template-of-twig-and-vue-js) a bit